# How to open same pdf file in two different tabs or windows in pdf xchange editor?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I want to open the same pdf file in different tabs or windows.
I tried to open the same file when I already opened it. However, pdf xchange editor did not perform any action.

I don't mean to split windows in [this article](https://www.tracker-software.com/knowledgebase/298-How-do-I-view-two-documents-at-the-same-time-in-PDF-XChange-Editor-or-PDF-XChange-Viewer).
I mean to open in a new, different tab or window.

Answer (score 1):

Use View->Document Tabs->New Document Window

[image]